# JQuery : How get Json Key And Value by and this append (insert into ) list (ul)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, getjson

Please take a look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xY7tx/3108/

When I run `getJSON` in the above sample, why is the `fail` part always triggered?

I would really appreciate if one tell me how with jQuery (or even with pure Javascript) How could get the key and value of the JSON file.

My goal is after getting the key (`title`) and the value (`video_url`) then insert them all into  a list `ul` which the items of the list are the keys and the `href` are their values. Thanks

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)._

Comment: If you check the console you'll see why the `fail` handler is always hit: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's not JSON data. You're `getJSON`ing an HTML page.

Try it with the following link:

```
$.getJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xldrx/kodi-persian-contents/master/movies/movies.json", function(d) {
        console.log(d);
    }).fail( function(d, textStatus, error) {
        alert("getJSON failed \n , status: " + textStatus + "\n "+ ", error: "+error + "\n")
    });
```

As for the list, not sure I fully understood your requirement, but is this what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/p77ymjgx/ ?

Comment: How does OP add this data to a `ul`?

Comment: @Zubzob , Thanks! now I've got the answer for my first part. i would really appreciate if you can help me how add this data to a ul? (I mean second part of question (key (title) as element of the list (ul) and the value (video_url) as href for each item? then  i would accept your answer as solution of this thread. Many Thanks!

Comment: @Zubzob Superb! Many Thanks! I have accepted your answer as solution for this Thread.